# wordpress htaccess rewriterule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my wordpress .htaccess file look like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

i want add my owm rewriterule but is not working
rule have to rewrite page/([a-z,A-Z]+).html$ to pages?page_name=$1

Comment: what did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also i recomend you to read [this post](http://audio.probudget.ru/programmirovanie/sobstvenniy-rewriterule-v-wordpress)
it shows how to add your custom rewriterule to WP

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rule to do what you ask for:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([a-z,A-Z]+).html$ pages?page_name=$1 [NC]
```

Placing this after `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` should do it.

Comment: it began to work only after:
1 - adding [NC,L] in the end of RewriteRule ^page/([a-z,A-Z]+).html$ pages?page_name=$1

Answer (score 0):

it began to work only after:

> 1. adding [NC,L] in the end of my RewriteRule
> 2. using absolute path `http://site.ru/pages?page_name=$1`